# Ionic and Firebase angularFire2 5.0.0 InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

im newbe and basically I'm trying to show a simple list in my HortalicasPage, what i missing?

I've made several attempts and none successfully, what am I missing?

Sorry for the question but I'm a beginner. Thank you very much

the stackoverflow is not letting me post the question, because this claiming that it has too much code and little description, I'm sorry for that too

hortalicas.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Item } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetalheHortalicaPage } from '../detalhe-hortalica/detalhe-hortalica';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "angularfire2/database";
import { FirebaseProvider } from '../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-hortalicas',
  templateUrl: 'hortalicas.html'
})
export class HortalicasPage {
  HortalicasList

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider, 
    afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {

      this.HortalicasList = firebaseProvider.getListHortalicias();

      console.log(this.HortalicasList);

      //this.database.list('shopping-list').valueChanges();;
  //  const HortalicaList = this.firebaseProvider.getListHortalicias();
  //this.HortalicaList = this.firebaseProvider.getListHortalicias().valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
 // this.firebaseProvider.getListHortalicias().valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
    //console.log(this.firebaseProvider.getListHortalicias().valueChanges());
    //firebaseProvider.getListHortalicias().valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
    //afDb.list<Item>('hortalicas').valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);

  }
  goToDetalheHortalica(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(DetalheHortalicaPage);
  }
}
```

hortalicas.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Hortalicas
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page6">
  <ion-list id="hortalicas-list7">
    <ion-searchbar placeholder="Buscar Hortaliça" name="SearchBarHortailica" id="hortalicas-search1"></ion-searchbar>
     <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of HortalicasList | async">
        <ion-item color="none" on-click="goToDetalheHortalica()" id="hortalicas-list-item19">
          <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <img />
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <h2>
              {{ item.name }}
              1
          </h2>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

provider firebase.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import { Item } from 'ionic-angular';
/*
  Generated class for the FirebaseProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseProvider {

  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log('Hello FirebaseProvider Provider');
  }

  getListHortalicias(){
    return this.afd.list<Item>('hortalicas')
  }


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a sample code since your code is very difficult to read due to too many commented out code. Hope you'll convert this to your use case.

```
hortalicasList : AngularFireList<any>;

constructor(){}

gethortalicasList  = (ev: any) : AngularFireList<any> {
  this.hortalicasList =  this.afDatabase.list('/Hortalicas', {
       query:{
        }
      }
     ).valueChanges();

    return this.hortalicasList;
}
```

Comment: thank you, im sorry about my commented line , I tried several ways. By the way, i put .valueChanges(); in the end of this.HortalicasList = firebaseProvider.getListHortalicias(); and works great. 
I did not quite understand, from what I know valueChanges is for when there are value changes in the list

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)